# Jenkins does not start jobs; "build planned"

Tags: linux, jenkins, amazon-ec2, jenkins-job-builder

I have migrated a Jenkins server (+ WebSphere) from a Linux server to an EC2 (AWS; Redhat) Linux machine (installed Jenkins on the EC2, then migrated var/lib/jenkins from the source server).

When I want to build the jobs, nothing happens, except that an info field with the inscription "build scheduled" appears. I cannot find the corresponding positions in the planned builds:

[!"build planned" screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLDRX.png) ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLDRX.png)

What do I have to do to get the job to run or that the log file is written at all?
Unfortunately, the log file is not described, so I cannot provide a more detailed error description.

In addition, no workspace exists (was not migrated). Jenkins says that this can be created by triggering a build. However, no builds start as already mentioned

Thanks in advance!

To solve the problem, I have already tried the migration again - nothing has improved.
I have also allocated sufficient TEMP memory etc. to the workspace. Didn't help either.
Various combinations (no user login, login as admin, etc.) have also not brought about any changes.

EDIT:
The settings are also overwritten each time the system is started.

The allocated swap and TEMP memory were removed from the settings after a restart, for example.
I had the same problem with the users & security settings.

Comment: Do you have any build executors available? If a build is scheduled, you should be able to observe it in a build queue. From there you should be able to access the build log where the reason of waiting is logged.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share the solution I have found, perhaps someone else is also experiencing this.

The problem was that Jenkins had ***no write permissions***. The plugins all threw an error.

After I gave Jenkins write permissions, these problems disappeared.